# Spring Data JPA custom functionality for all repositories

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I tried to implement custom functionality for all of my repositories (I used Packt Spring Data sample as base). I would like to override some of the default behaviors.

First I implemented:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends AbstractModel, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    @Override
    public void delete(final T t);

    public T save(final T entity);  
}
```

AbstractModel is for logic delete:

```
public interface AbstractModel {

    public boolean isDeleted();

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted);
}
```

`GenericBaseRepository` implements custom functions. I need logical delete function. And I would like to override save to use always merge to handle saving of cascade objects.

```
public class GenericBaseRepository<T extends AbstractModel, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    Class<T> type;

    public GenericBaseRepository(final JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityMetadata, final EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityMetadata, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(final T t) {
        t.setDeleted(true);
        save(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(final ID id) {
        final T deleted = findOne(id);

        if (deleted == null) {
            logger.warn("{} Record not found: id={}", getClass(), id);
        }

        deleted.setDeleted(true);
        save(deleted);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(final S entity) {
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

`BaseRepositoryFactoryBean` initializes `GenericBaseRepository`

```
public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new BaseRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    protected static class BaseRepositoryFactory<T extends AbstractModel, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private final EntityManager entityManager;

        public BaseRepositoryFactory(final EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);

            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getTargetRepository(final RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return new GenericBaseRepository<T, I>((JpaEntityInformation<T, I>) getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType()), entityManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(final RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return GenericBaseRepository.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of spring config xml:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="sample.project.repository" />
```

Custom classes and interfaces are in this package and there are concrete repository interfaces too.

I also have configuration annotation on my `@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"sample.project.repository", "sample.project.service"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"sample.project.repository"}, repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
```

Standard Spring Data functionality works fine, but custom overrides are not. Save and delete functions are not overridden. When calling them original parent methods are executed.

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the repository factory bean on the `jpa:repositories` config element? Something like: `<jpa:repositories base-package="sample.project.repository" factory-class="sample.project.repository.BaseRepositoryFactoryBean"/>`